# How do I add audio blob file to AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I am using an API key which returns audio data which I convert to a blob

```
const blobItem = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
```

(this gives me a URL like blob:http:// ....)

How do I add this to an s3 bucket?

Here's my attempt:

```
const blobItem = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
            
let file = new File([blobItem], 'filename2', { type: 'audio/mpeg', lastModified: Date.now() })
console.log(file);
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
     "Body": file,
     "Bucket": BUCKET_NAME,
     "Key": "filename2.mpeg",
});
const newResponse = await client.send(command);
```

The result that is added to aws is just a blank file

Comment: Does it work? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It returns a blank file in the bucket

Comment: I'm not a Node person, but the documentation for [`PutObjectCommand()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/s3/command/PutObjectCommand/) says that `Body` is a `StreamingBlobPayloadInputTypes` that can be `string | Uint8Array | Buffer | Readable`. I notice that `File` isn't listed as a type. I found [How to Upload a File to Amazon S3 with NodeJS | Saturn Cloud Blog](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-with-nodejs/) with some code that uses `fs.readFileSync(fileName)` to read the file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your help, unfortunately, that blog is for an old version of javascript aws.